# SQL for previous value in column for last 30 days

Tags: oracle-10g

[image: Sample Table]

I'm looking for SQL which give me the job, present position, previous position, change date for last 30 days...

Much Appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: *job, present position, ... change date* - common SELECT. *previous position* - use LAG() function. *for last 30 days* - common WHERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised

```
SELECT id, j1.position, j2.position, j1.change_date
FROM tb_job j1
JOIN tb_job j2
   on j2.id = j1.id
   and j2.change_date < j1.change_date
   and j2.change_date > (j1.change_date - INTERVAL '30' DAY)
WHERE not exists
(select * from tb_job j
 where j.id = j1.id
 and j.change_date < j1.change_date
 and j.change_date > j2.change_date
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I think I was not explaining the question better before.. just to add clarity.. I have audit table with columns value getting updated all the time... I was looking for query to get current and previous value on a column if both are different in last 30 days.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ redsimon ---- It worked well !